# Couldn't perform delete operation for New users and updated users (CRUD OPERATION)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, crud

I was working on crud operation project, I was using tsx and nodejs fetching JSON Data, When I wrote the delete operation the JSON pre-written Users were able to delete but when I create and update user it didn't work, It shows

Users.tsx:65

```
    DELETE http://localhost:3000/user/26 404 (Not Found)
```

#### Delete operation Code

`<button onClick={(e) => handleDelete(users.id)} className="dlte-btn">`

```
  function handleDelete(id) {
    const Conf = window.confirm("Do you want to delete");
    if (Conf) {
      axios
        .delete("http://localhost:3000/user/" + id)
        .then((res) => {
          toast.error("User has been Deleted", { position: "top-right" });
          navigate("/");
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  }
```

#### Update Operation Code

```
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/user/` + id, data).then((res) => {
      alert("data update successfully!");
      navigate("/");
    });
  }
```

```
 <input type="number"  min="1" placeholder="Enter ID" className="form-control" value={data.id} onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, id: e.target.value })}/>
```

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" className="form-control" value={data.name} onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, name: e.target.value })} />
```

#### Create Operation Code

```
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({ id: "", name: "" });
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function Submit(event: { preventDefault: () => void }) {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/user", inputData)
      .then((res) => {
        toast.success("User Added Successfully", { position: "top-right" });
        navigate("/");
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

```
<input type="number" min="1" placeholder="Enter ID" className="form-control" onChange={(e) => setInputData({ ...inputData, id: e.target.value })} />
```

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" className="form-control" onChange={(e) => setInputData({ ...inputData, name: e.target.value })}/>
```

Tbh I couldn't figure it out what to do, this is my first CRUD tsx project.
I'am expecting that delete operation should work on update and create users too, not just pre json fetched data

#### server side code

```
app.delete("/user/:id", (req, res) => {
  try {

    const userId = parseInt(req.params.id);


    const userIndex = USERS.users.findIndex((user) => user.id === userId);


    if (userIndex === -1) {
      return res.status(404).send("User not found");
    }

    USERS.users.splice(userIndex, 1);


    res.status(200).json(USERS);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});
```

Comment: it looks like the id of the user (26) does not exist in your data source

Comment: Actually I created the users of ID 26. here is the code for createing user    
```        
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({ id: "", name: "" });
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function Submit(event: { preventDefault: () => void }) {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/user", inputData)
      .then((res) => {
        toast.success("User Added Successfully", { position: "top-right" });
        navigate("/");
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

Comment: Could the issue be serverside?

Comment: I wrote the code above could you check it?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).